# Return list of String from dialog

Tags: arrays, list, javafx, dialog

I have a dialog with few textfields. I want dialog to return these result as a list of String. 
Here is an example how to return a Pair of String:

```
    dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
             return new Pair<>(slotRequired.getText(), baseOffset.getText());
    });
```

Do you know how to do it with a list of String ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the dialog a `Dialog<List<String>>` and do

```
dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(slotRequired.getText());
    result.add(baseOffset.getText());
    // add as many times as you need...
    return result ;
});
```

or, more succinctly:

```
dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> 
    Arrays.asList(slotRequired.getText(), baseOffset.getText() /*, as many as you need...*/));
```

Comment: Thats what I want. Thank you :)